# Playing animation during x seconds using setInterval

Tags: javascript, performance, setinterval

I want to display an animated number from 0 to max value y during x seconds. I have tried this following code but it take too much to complete and clear the interval.

```js
jQuery('.numbers').each(function(item, index) {
  const $obj = jQuery(this);
  let objValue = parseInt($obj.text()),
    currentValue = 0,
    speed = 1,
    time = 4000,
    step = Math.floor(objValue / time);
  $obj.text(currentValue);
  let interVal = setInterval(() => {
    if (currentValue >= objValue) {
      clearInterval(interVal);
      $obj.text(objValue);
    }
    $obj.text(currentValue);
    currentValue += step
  }, speed);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='numbers'>7586</span>
<span class='numbers'>147520</span>
```

How do I play this animation during exactly `time` seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better not to depend on the timing of `setInterval()`, but the real problem in your script is that you use the floored value to decide the new value to print out.

It is better to use [Window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and create a `update()` function that prints the current number based on the *real* time elapsed.

```js
let start, previousTimeStamp;
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.numbers');

requestAnimationFrame(update);

function update(timestamp) {
  if (start === undefined) {
    start = timestamp;
  }
  const elapsed = timestamp - start;
  [...numbers].forEach(elm => {
    if(!elm.dataset.start){
      elm.dataset.start = elm.textContent;
    }
    let start = parseInt(elm.dataset.start);
    elm.textContent = Math.floor(start / 4000 * elapsed);
  });
  if (elapsed < 4000) {
    previousTimeStamp = timestamp;
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }else {
    start = undefined;
    [...numbers].forEach(elm => {
      elm.textContent = elm.dataset.start;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<span class='numbers'>7586</span>
<span class='numbers'>147520</span>
```